# How to set a static property only when it is nil?

Tags: swift

I'd like to be able to call a property `ConferenceNumberDirectory.att` where if the number directory/array exists we return it, if it doesn't we parse the entry.

```
///Builds, stores, retrieves and queries conference number directories.
class ConferenceNumberDirectory {

static var att: [ConferenceNumber] = {
    build(from: ConferenceNumberDirectory.jsonArray)
    print("Am I lazy!?")
    return ConferenceNumberDirectory.att
}()
```

`build` is a function that modifies `ConferenceNumberDirectory.att`. When I try to call it the emulator appears to jam and the memory usage steadily rises until I stop running.
Is there a way I can do this using a computed property?

Comment: Do you know what recursion is?

Comment: @rmaddy ah lol I see what I've done.

Comment: @rmaddy Is there a way to access what the existing value of the property without calling the computed function again?

I could create a separate `private` `att2` property to check the value  against but it feels dirty.

Comment: would a singleton work better in your case then using static?  You could then use lazy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a lazy computed property. Simply do:

```
class ConferenceNumberDirectory {

static var att: [ConferenceNumber] = {
    let result = build(from: ConferenceNumberDirectory.jsonArray)
    print("Am I lazy!?")
    return result
}()
```

And change your `build` method return a value instead of attempting to set `att`.